# Re-adjust transition speed in chain of animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation

The following code (1) moves an image down and to the left, (2) rotates it 180 degrees, (3) then blasts it across the screen to the right.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsyLooo/)

Note that the animation transition speed is slowed down when the object is rotated, so that it appears to turn and not merely to flip.

The problem is that this causes the 3rd part of the animation to also go very slowly... no longer a blast, more like a mosey.

```
$('.moving_image').delay(7000).animate({
    'left' : '18%',
    'top' : '55%',
    'width': '5vw'
},5500,function(){
        $('.moving_image').css({'transform':'rotateY(180deg)','transition-duration':'2s'});
        $('.moving_image').delay(2000).css({'transition-duration':'0s'}).animate({
            'left' : '101%',
            'top'  : '50%',
            'width': '15vw'
        },200,'easeInExpo')
});
```

Note the unsuccessful attempt to re-adjust the animation speed in line 7, with the addition of this snippet:

```
.delay(2000).css({'transition-duration':'0s'})
```

Sadly, it merely negated the previous `2s` slowdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional `animate` function to change `transition-duration`:
http://jsfiddle.net/mpsyLooo/4/

BTW, I really recommend [TimelineMax](http://greensock.com/timelinemax) or [CSS3 keyframes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) to animations like this.